# union overlapping polygons until no overlap

Tags: python, algorithm, gis, arcgis, shapely

I have a list of geometries(could be a point or polygon) and I need to union the geometries that overlap(or contained within another geometry) in to one geometry. Any ideas on how to do this efficiently using shapely? I believe I should be using rtree but not sure how and where exactly I should use it.

Ex:

```
from shapely import geometry as gs
geometries = [gs.Polygon(((0,0), (0,10), (10, 10), (10, 0))),
              gs.Point((5,5)), gs.Point((30, 30))]

#output should be :
Polygon((0,0), (0,10), (10, 10), (10, 0)), Point((30, 30))
```

Comment: this seems pretty broad, have you made any attempts to do this yourself? How -specifically- are your geometries defined? Can you easily detect where two shapes intersect?

Comment: yes, I can do that easily.

Comment: You should probably ask this at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: in case you are willing to use PostGIS, then `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` seems to do what you are after, i.e., it constructs clusters of geometries on top of which you can then call `ST_Union` to merge them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shapely.ops.unary_union` will perform the union of any geometry types and produce a `shapely.geometry.GeometryCollection` (set of geometries). This is the function you should be using ([docs here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union)).

Comment: I think that OP is probably more interested in how to efficiently construct the individual groups of overlapping geometries (the union of which is then calculated)

Comment: @ewcz I am confident that my answer serves the original question. `unary_union` performs the union of any number of geometries. It produces the minimal result and returns disjoint geometries when necessary.

Comment: The link is now incorrect, can it be updated please to: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union